# How do I fetch column values and not column names in SQLITE3 (my columns are dates)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make an attendance-taking program with Python, SQLite and TKinter. My columns are dates (class meeting dates) and the contents are time stamps. I am now attempting to get the list of students who attended on a particular date to show up in my listbox.

```
self.date = time.strftime("%d %b %Y")
...
self.cur.execute("SELECT name FROM table WHERE '{column_name}' IS NOT NULL".format(column_name = self.date))
names = self.cur.fetchall()
```

When I tried printing the names, I got tuples with the name and the column_name, but I was expecting column values and not the latter. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use string formatting to set the column name: that's where the problem seems to lie. I tried running similar code on a database on my machine, and I did not get the tuple logic error when I removed the string formatting. Simply enter the column name manually (that shouldn't be a problem).